# What is "using" doing in this instance, and what is being stored?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, using

I have the following class:

```
class Foo{

}

class Bar{
public:

     using meth = Foo* (*)(int a, std::string b);
}
```

Can someone explain what the line means:

```
     using meth = Foo* (*)(int a, std::string b);
```

It seems to me that this is a way of storing a pointer to a constructor or something. If someone can explain, I would appreciate it.

Please feel free to edit the question itself to make it more descriptive - if I knew what this code did, I wouldn't ask the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
using meth = Foo* (*)(int a, std::string b);
```

makes `meth` a shorthand (type alias) for the lengthy function pointer type declaration.

It can be used like:

```
Foo* bar(int a, std::string b);

meth baz = bar;
```

Comment: But Foo is empty, and does not contain any functions. So what is being stored? Also, I don't understand what your second code block is doing. It looks like a function declaration in the first line, and then you are assigning it to meth. I don't know what to make of it, and can't understand why you would do it.

Comment: It's a function pointer for a global function. `Foo*` is just the return type.

Comment: So are you saying that ( * ) denotes a function, (int a,std::string b), the parameters, and Foo* the return type ?

Comment: @John It's the `(*)(...)` part that says that it's a pointer to a function. `(*)` by itself is just a pointer.

Answer (score 4):

In that situation it's just a new form of creating a type-alias, just like using `typedef`. It says that the type-alias `meth` is a pointer to a function taking an `int` and a `std::string` argument and returning a pointer to `Foo`. You can then use it do declare variables, like e.g.

```
meth walter;
```

You can then assign to the variable `walter` like any other variable.

The type-alias is stored in the memory for the compiler, it's not written to the object or executable file, it's just used by and inside the compiler.

---

It should be noted that like many other things in C++ the context is important, and that the keyword `using` can do different things in different contexts.

It can be used to create type-aliases (as in the question), it can be used to create namespace aliases, it can be used to pull in symbols from one scope into another scope (the most common being, unfortunately) to pull in all symbols from the `std` namespace into the global scope).

Comment: Saul never did meth anyway. Can this be used to point to constructors ?

Comment: @John Constructors or destructors cannot be used as function pointers, these are special methods.

Comment: @John No it can't be used to point to non-static member function, only non-member functions or `static` member functions. If you want a pointer to a non-static member function you need e.g. `void (Foo::*)(...)`. Rather it' is now a function which can create (and return) an instance of `Foo`.

Comment: @John And as πάντα ῥεῖ says, you can't have pointers (or other function-wrappers) to constructors or destructors, they are a special case. You might instead by interested in [the factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming))?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg excellent -Coincidentally I was trying to build a factory.  can you explain what you mean by void (Foo::*)(...) ?